# What is the purpose of `BRepLib::BuildCurves3d` calls in the OpenCASCADE tutorial?

Tags: opencascade

As an OpenCASCADE newbie, I am reading the OpenCASCADE tutorial:

https://www.opencascade.com/doc/occt-7.4.0/overview/html/occt__tutorial.html

There are following two curious calls:

```
BRepLib::BuildCurves3d(threadingWire1);
BRepLib::BuildCurves3d(threadingWire2);
```

The tutorial explains the need for these two calls in this way:

> Remember that these wires were built out of a surface and 2D curves. One important data item is missing as far as these wires are concerned: there is no information on the 3D curves. Fortunately, you do not need to compute this yourself, which can be a difficult task since the mathematics can be quite complex. When a shape contains all the necessary information except 3D curves, Open CASCADE Technology provides a tool to build them automatically. In the `BRepLib` tool package, you can use the `BuildCurves3d` method to compute 3D curves for all the edges of a shape.

which I did not find entirely clear.

Imagine that I have constructed some `TopoDS_Shape` object.

How can I, in general, figure out whether `BRepLib::BuildCurves3d` call is necessary or not?

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can get the 3D curve of an edge (take from `BRepExtrema_DistanceSS.cxx`):

```
Standard_Real aFirst, aLast;
Handle(Geom_Curve) pCurv = BRep_Tool::Curve(E, aFirst, aLast);
```

If you have not created the 3D curves, `pCurv` will be a null handle. Using it will result in segmentation faults.

I have been excited about where the 3D curves are actually used. Therefore I have tried several algorithms. These are the algorithms I have tried where the 3D curves are **not** used:

- Visualizing
- Export to BREP
- Export to STEP
- Length Measurement
- Checking Whether a Wire Is Closed or Ordered

The only algorithm I have found where the 3D curves are used are extrema/distance computations with `BRepExtrema_DistShapeShape`. You will not be able to use this class if you have not created the 3D curves.